# Referring to a specific place on page

Tags: javascript, html

I know that in Javascript `document.location.href = "#my_id"` tells the browser to display the same page starting from element with id="my_id".
In this case, the address that appears in the address bar is in the following format: `my_page_address#my_id`

Is this the only method to refer to a specific place on a page ?
I'm looking for a method that will not show `my_id` in the address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `document.getElementbyId("my_id").scrollIntoView()`?

Answer (score 4):

Most browsers implement the `scrollIntoView` method ([MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536730(VS.85).aspx)) on elements. That works on IE6 and up (at least), Firefox and other Gecko-based browsers, Chrome and other WebKit-based browsers, Opera, etc.

`scrollIntoView` example using an element retrieved by ID:

```
document.getElementById("my_id").scrollIntoView();
```

Of course, this requires that Javascript be enabled (I'm assuming this is okay because of the Javascript tag on the question :-) ).

You can also scroll to specific coordinates on the page using [`window.scrollTo`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/win_scrollto.html).