# On load go to specific place

Tags: javascript, html

So i have some troubles getting to the right place when loading the page. I would like to when i open start.php to go to start.php#forside.

Right now i have something that works a little but its not the right way to do it and i would like something more stable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <title>Ane Lagoni Jewelry</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="loadBackground" src="img/baggrund.jpg" alt="" />
    <span id="counter">0</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function countdown() {
        var i = document.getElementById('counter');
        if (parseInt(i.innerHTML) <= 0) {
            location.href = 'start.php#forside';
        }
        i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    }
    setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },75);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Would it be possible with some js?

EDIT:

i solved it with

```
<?php
    header('Location: start.php#forside');
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referring to a specific place on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676254/referring-to-a-specific-place-on-page)

Comment: Did the code in my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```js
var timeLeft = 5;
var interval;

function timer() {
  timeLeft--;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = timeLeft;
  if (timeLeft == 0) {
    location.href = 'start.php#forside';
  }
};

interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Ane Lagoni Jewelry</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="loadBackground" src="img/baggrund.jpg" alt="" />
  <span id="counter"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to `#forside` when the page loads, you could use `scrollIntoView()` instead of replacing `location.href`.

```
if (parseInt(i.innerHTML) <= 0) document.getElementById('forside').scrollIntoView()
```

Further documentation: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: The code i wrote up there was actually from the file index.php. which only contains the written code and directs to the file start.php which is the actual site. Would it be possible without the index? hop you understand